# Menu Items that change the application's view

Tags: c#, .net

I've been all up and down [this tutoria](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html)l.

I can't for the life of me figure out how when my app loads to have 1 screen, then when a menu item is clicked to show another screen.  I get the idea of having multiple forms, but is that the solution I need here?

From what I've read I understand new forms to be essentially new windows.  If that's right, that doesn't sound like what I need.

My users start off with a blank window other than a menu (I'm gonna fill it in later), but I want for `File -> Settings` to load a settings form.  Ideally not in a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a MDI window. They are window containers of other windows.

You create a parent form, and then you change which child form is the active form on the menu item click events.  This requires you make a parent MDI form, and a child MDI form for each of the different views you want of your document.  The menu items then switch which child MDI form is the active one.

Comment: It doesn't look like that's something that is offered in the UI toolbox... I'll have to look into that further tomorrow.

Comment: Right click project, add new item, scroll down to MDI Parent Form.

Comment: @Webnet There are a lot of items in the UI toolbox that aren't exposed by default.

Comment: I guess you could also just add a MenuStrip to your form which is probably all your class is asking for.  MDI parent forms look more complicated than the website you posted.

Comment: I have a menu strip right now, it's the hiding/showing of the UI elements that I'm a little unsure about how to do.  What's good practice in how to group them?  Are there some kind of containers I should be using?

Comment: @Webnet Thanks for the link. It helped me something with my project.

Comment: @Webnet To do what you are alluding to you use an MDI parent form, and you change the document context when a menu item is selected. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Webnet Another link to help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973874.aspx